# Why does my AO bake have hard edges?

Tags: texturing, workflow, texture-baking, baking, ambient-occlusion

I'm trying to learn how to sculpt high poly and bake into a low poly game ready mesh. I'm at the stage where I need to bake an AO map, but mine doesn't look like other examples I see. Here's what it bakes to:

[image]

I did the normal map first, which looks how I'd expect it to look:

[image]

For reference, here's the low poly and high poly model side by side:

[image]

And here are my settings:

[image]

Is this how some AO maps should look, or is something wrong?

Edit: Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-wlCftrj-DFqkfEpbUAwH2XgP2xgO9JZ/view?usp=sharing) to the blend file.

Comment: No, I don't think your AO should look like that, from what I'm seeing of your high poly.  Can you provide a file?  First thing I'd suspect would be hidden, occluding objects.

Comment: @Nathan You bet - here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-wlCftrj-DFqkfEpbUAwH2XgP2xgO9JZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: When I do the bake as set up in the file, from HP to RetopoFloor, I don't get the same texture you're showing.  My bake looks reasonable.  Is it possible you didn't select in the right order?  RetopoFloor should be active selection (yellow, not orange.)

Comment: @Nathan I just tried it again and it's working. I wasn't selecting the opposite direction as I have no material setup on the HP version so it wouldn't even start the process.

So sorry to waste your time! (FWIW, I did a rebake easily 5 times before posting this!)

Do you want to post the answer (make sure you select correctly, silly) and I'll mark you as answering?

Comment: Nah, there's not enough information to really answer the question.  It didn't work, and now it does, that's all we know.  I suppose if I cared more, I'd probably mark the question for deletion instead of answering it.  But as long as you're good, I'm good :)